# Backup or export Azure SQL Database with Row-Level Security

Tags: sql-server, backup, azure-sql-database, row-level-security

I'm having difficulties exporting a Sql Azure database using Row-Level Security.

When using the Export method the following error occurs:

> Error encountered during the service operation.
> Could not export schema and data from database.
> One or more errors occurred.
> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'D' to data type int.

Obviously the RLS causes these problems. But I don't see any other way to export the database.

I need to run a script to mutate data and making a backup beforehand would make me a lot safer.

Anyone got a working backup strategy?

### update

This export button
[image: Export button]

Comment: What export method you are using?  Are you exporting to Azure SQL database?

Comment: Updated the question. The export should create a .bacpac file.

Comment: Any luck on this? @rdkleine

Comment: I'm afraid not. There is a method I've wanted to try is to duplicate the database then remove RLS and lastly backup the database. This will lose the RLS obviously but I needed this for debugging purposes.